# QtGui's Tooltip is cut off in Windows 7 (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, tooltip, qtgui

I am trying to add tooltips to some `QtGui.QPushButton()`.

Everything works as wanted, but sometimes, my tooltips are cut off, randomly in my eyes.
I already tried to change the font, but no effect.

I suspect, it has something to do with windows, because my teammates using OS MAC did not experience the problem. Anybody an idea how to handle this?

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton()
...
tool_tip = "testmsg"
btn.setToolTip(tool_tip)
QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('OldEnglish', 10))
...
```

[image: should be: "Transformer"]

Comment: My uneducated guess: `setToolTip` calculates the required width of the tooltip, and doesn't bother to recalculate it later when if you change the font. Try moving `setFont` up a line so it occurs before `setToolTip`.

Comment: No chance. I added `setFont` later on to try something out. So the fault was already there without the command, unfortunally.